# Is it a good practice to have an abstract parent and an abstract child classes in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class

I have 2 level inheritance, such that the parent is an abstract class that initialize common things for its first level children.
In addition each first level child is also a base abstract class that initialize additional unique parameters for the second (and last) level inheriting classes

The classes will look similar to the following:

The abstract parent:

```
class AbstractParent(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__():
        <initialize common stuff>

    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_method():
        pass
```

First level abstract child:

```
class AbstractChild(AbstractParent, metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init___():
        AbstractParent.__init__(self)
        <initialize common stuff relevant for AbstractChild>

    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_method():
        pass
```

The second and last level child:

```
class Child(AbstractChild):

    def __init___():
        AbstractChild.__init__(self)

    def abstract_method():
        <implementation of something...>
```

Is it good practice to have multi-level inheritance such that multiple levels are abstract similar to what I presented above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the class system of your projects requires it, then it's good practice. It all depends on what you're trying to implement.

For example. You could have a school that offers `Course`s. These courses can be `Cooking` and `Painting`. Now for cooking we have different styles `Italian`, `Greek`,....

`Course` and `Cooking` can be abstract here since we'll never have to create an instance of a generic `Course`.

Is this good practice? That all depends on the contents of your classes.  Does `Cooking` contain extra information that `Course` doesn't have? Maybe a list of ingredients?

However we may want `Cooking` not to be an abstract class. Maybe a general cooking class is also possible.

It all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, the example you provided can be reflected to my case. The parent (e.g. Course) initialize methods and parameter that are common to all children. The first level children classes (e.g. Cooking) also initialize additional stuff that are only relevant to it. In addition the parent and first level child cannot be ever instantiated (In my case). Only the second level children classes (E.g. Italian cooking course) can actually be instantiated.

Comment: In that case it's probably reasonable to use multiple abstract inheritance. If you're fairly new to oop, it might be worth to also look into composition instead of inheritance but inheritance deff isn't a bad idea.